# Get first IObservable event without blocking the thread/task that wants it

Tags: c#, multithreading, reactive

I am looking at using `IObservable` to get a response in a request-response environment within a c# `async` methods and replace some older callback based code, but I am finding that if a value is pushed (`Subject.OnNext`) to the observable but `FirstAsync` is not yet at the await, then the `FirstAsync` is never given that message.

Is there a straightforward way to make it work, without a 2nd task/thread plus synchronisation?

```
public async Task<ResponseMessage> Send(RequestMessage message)
{
    var id = Guid.NewGuid();
    var ret = Inbound.FirstAsync((x) => x.id == id).Timeout(timeout); // Never even gets invoked if response is too fast
    await DoSendMessage(id, message);
    return await ret; // Will sometimes miss the event/message
}

// somewhere else reading the socket in a loop
// may or may not be the thread calling Send
Inbound = subject.AsObservable();
while (cond)
{
    ...
    subject.OnNext(message);
}
```

I cant put the `await` for the `FirstAsync` simply before I send the request, as that would prevent the request being sent.

Comment: using TaskCompletionSource is an option?

Comment: What would that look like? Say setting up a subscription that sets a tcs result then unsubscribes itself. Then do a send and then await the tcs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `await` will subscribe to the observable. You can separate the subscription from the `await` by calling `ToTask`:

```
public async Task<ResponseMessage> Send(RequestMessage message)
{
  var id = Guid.NewGuid();
  var ret = Inbound.FirstAsync((x) => x.id == id).Timeout(timeout).ToTask();
  await DoSendMessage(id, message);
  return await ret;
}
```

Comment: Guessing that is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.threading.tasks.taskobservableextensions.totask(v=vs.103).aspx ? The description doesnt seem to really explain this. But am I to understand that the chain of `Where`, `FirstAsync`, etc. is just like "pending", and a `ToTask`, `await`, (or other stuff to?) makes it active and start observing events?

Comment: Yes. Like other LINQ constructs, Rx builds up a "definition" with its operators, and it's only executed when it's subscribed to (in this case, `await`ing an observable, or converting to `Task`).

Answer (score 1):

I took a closer look and there is a very easy solution to your problem by just converting hot into cold observable. Replace `Subject` with `ReplaySubject`. Here is the article: http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html.

> Here is the explanation:
>
> The Replay extension method allows you take an existing observable
>   sequence and give it 'replay' semantics as per ReplaySubject. As a
>   reminder, the ReplaySubject will cache all values so that any late
>   subscribers will also get all of the values.